# Accidentally deleted libGLEW

Tags: ubuntu

I accidentally deleted `libGLEW.so.2.0.0` from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

The problem is, reinstalling `libglew-dev` does not bring this file back:

```
apt get install libglew-dev
```

just brings back the `libGLEW.so` to `libGLEW.so.2.0.0` symbolic link.

But the target of the link does not exist so it's no good.

How can I restore the missing file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall the library package itself:

```
apt install --reinstall libglew2.0
```

(on Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10).